# How do I pass headers from nginx X-Accel-Redirect back to the browser?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm using the nginx X-Accel-Redirect feature where a proxied backend (A) can "internally redirect" nginx to reprocess a new URI (B) as if that were the one originally given by the client browser.

It works great in making request B (also proxied)and returning B's resulting headers back to the client browser.  So far so good.

But also I have some headers from A which I'd like to pass along too.  In other words, merge a handful of headers from A in with the result from B.

How can I do this?  I've tried

```
add_header  X-My-Header  $http_x_my_header;
```

But that `$http_x_my_header` variable is empty, presumably because the *original* request didn't have it.  I've also tried `$upstream_x_my_header` but that's empty too.  I've tried things like `proxy_pass_header X-My-Header;` but no.

Answer (score 2):

After trial and error, I found the `$upstream_http_...` headers to be working when first assigned to a variable;

So with your example that would become something like this;

```
  set $my_header '$upstream_http_x_my_header';
  add_header  X-My-Header  $my_header;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to nginx manual for [proxy_set_header](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_set_headerhttp://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header):

*If value is empty string, then header will not be sent to upstream.*

Try using `proxy_set_header X-My-Header "OK"` or perhaps a variable you'd like to use as value. That should pass it to the proxy as well as the user.

Comment: `proxy_set_header` is for passing headers _to_ the upstream; the question is about using the headers _from_ the upstream.